# IBAction for a SearchBar in swift

Tags: swift, ibaction, searchbar

I need to control when an user type in a SearchBar. It's easy using a text field but I can't find the way to do that with a Search Bar because I cannot use IBActions.

Answer (score 1):

UISearchBar have property `id <UISearchBarDelegate> delegate`. See the protocol and you will get you want.